# Prevent resizing textarea in <td> from resizing entire table

Tags: html-table, resize, textarea

I have a textarea in a td element. Currently, when the text area is resized to a width beyond the width of the td element, the entire table resizes to keep the textarea element within the td.

Is there a way to allow the textarea to resize beyond the containing td?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `div` with fixed size inside the td around the textarea: 
http://jsfiddle.net/kvKZu/4/

(reposting comment as answer)

Comment: I need to amend this, as the solution revealed a related issue: The **height** of the td with the textarea varies widely, so I can't explicitly set a height value on the div. I need to allow for variances in the height of the td's content, but still allow the textarea to be dragged outside of the enclosing div/td. (It'd be nice to be able to explicitly set the height of the textarea based on its contents, for that matter...). Should I put this in a new question?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... Can you post an example of the problem? The height of the div is just 1px so it shouldn't cause any problems. (Also, what about just disallowing vertical resize altogether? That seems most logical to me in most cases).

Comment: In the table I'm working on there are two columns with edit and delete buttons - about 100px each, give or take, then there are three columns with city, state and county names, about 120 px, give or take. The column with the textbox is the problem child. That has a list of zip code from as few as 10 to well over several hundred zip codes in a few cases. So, the rows are wildly varied in height due to the zip code column and I at least need the textarea to resize beyond the td container, but still allow for the varied height from row to row.

Comment: The question as I originally presented it was answered by Amon. My last comment introduced new items that can and should be addressed in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `max-width` and `max-height` style properties on the textarea. Take a look at:
http://jsfiddle.net/kvKZu/
You can also set them dynamically with javascript if the width and height of the containing row or column is not known in advanced.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I'm looking for. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. (It could also be that I had "td" in angle brackets, which prevented them from showing in the post.) I want to allow the textarea to go out **beyond** the width of the enclosing <td> tag if the user drags it out that wide.

Comment: ok, I think I understand now. Maybe this works?
Adding a div with fixed size inside the td and around the textedit
http://jsfiddle.net/kvKZu/3/

Comment: Yes, the jsFiddle works as I need it to. A question, though: is this line <td id="container-td" width="300px; overlow:hidden"> correct in syntax? Overflow is spelled wrong, but it still works correctly...

Comment: you're right, sorry. I spelled it wrong and didn't even put it in the correct attribute. overflow is not needed here, you can remove that.

Answer (score 0):

I found that applying the style table-layout:fixed to the table fixed this problem.